# Saving an Image as bitmap file and display it in label

Tags: java, awt

I want to grab a fingerprint image, display it to a label and save it as bitmap file. After swiping a finger to a reader, an image will be generated and that image must be displayed in a label and then save. Here is my code:

```
static class ABS_IMAGE
{
    int width;
    int height;
    int colorCount;
    int horizontalDpi;
    int verticalDpi;
    byte [] ImageData;

    ABS_IMAGE()
    {
        ImageData = new byte[55296];
    }
}

public class displayImage
{

private ABS_IMAGE _image = new ABS_IMAGE();

BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(_image.width, _image.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);     

JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(null, "bmp");
fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter);

if(fileChooser.showSaveDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
{

    try {

        // Save the image as bitmap file
        File file = new File("", fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getName() + ".bmp");

        ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "bmp", new File("filename.bmp"));


    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// Display Finger print image                   
FingerPrintImage formFingerPrintImage = new FingerPrintImage(this, true, _image.width, _image.height, _image.ImageData);
formFingerPrintImage.setVisible(true);

}
```

Here's the code of my second form where th image is being displayed:

```
public FingerPrintImage(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal, int width, int height, byte[] imageData) 
{
    super(parent, modal);

    initComponents();

    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        Dimension size = this.getSize();
        screenSize.height = screenSize.height/2;
        screenSize.width = screenSize.width/2;
        size.height = size.height/2;
        size.width = size.width/2;
        int y = screenSize.height - size.height;
        int x = screenSize.width - size.width;
        this.setLocation(x, y);

    _fpWidth = width;
    _fpHeight = height;

    _image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);

    displayImage(imageData);

    src = toBufferedImage(_image);

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(src);
        LabelImage.setIcon(icon);


}

private void initComponents()
{
    setResizable(false);

    //setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 238, 494);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JButton ButtonOk = new JButton("OK");
    ButtonOk.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                dispose();
            }
    });
    ButtonOk.setBounds(133, 432, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(ButtonOk);

    LabelImage = new JLabel("");
    LabelImage.setBounds(10, 11, 212, 410);
    contentPane.add(LabelImage);

}

private void displayImage(byte[] imageData)
{
        int ctr = 0;

        for(int j = 0; j < this._fpHeight; j++)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < this._fpWidth; i++)
            {
                _image.setRGB(i, j, imageData[ctr]);
                ctr++;
            }
        }
}

public void paint(Graphics g) 
{ 
    g.drawImage(src, (this.getSize().width - _fpWidth) / 2, (this.getSize().height - _fpHeight) / 2 , null); // see javadoc for more info on the parameters
    g.setColor(Color.red);

}
```

Comment: Can you describe your exact problem and formulate a question?

Comment: Actually, I managed to display the image even without a label. However, I don't know what type of BufferedImage to use.  If Im going to use BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY, the displayed image is color gray. The other type is yellow. I want the image to be displayed as black.